# How to construct — based on physics-type notation — a magical simplex $\mathcal{W}$ of bipartite qutrits?

Tags: matrix, physics, tensors, operators, projection

I have a short *Mathematica* program:

```
S[0] = {1, 0, 0}; S[1] = {0, 1, 0}; S[2] = {0, 0, 1};

Omega[0, 0] = (1/Sqrt[3]) Sum[KroneckerProduct[S[s], S[s]], {s, 0, 2}]

w = Exp[2 Pi I/3];

Do[
 If[{k, l} != {0, 0}, 
  Omega[k, l] = 
   (1/Sqrt[3]) 
    Sum[KroneckerProduct[w^(k (s - l)) (S[s] - S[l]), S[s]], {s, 0, 2}] 
     Omega[0, 0]], 
 {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 2}]

Do[
 P[k, l] = 
  ArrayReshape[Outer[Times, Omega[k, l], ConjugateTranspose[Omega[k, l]]], {9, 9}], 
 {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 2}];

Do[
 Print[{k, l, FullSimplify[Sum[P[k, l][[i, i]], {i, 1, 9}]]}], 
 {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 2}]
```

by which I'm attempting to implement the construction (quoting from the beginning of sec. IV of https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1403):

> We start with a maximally entangled pure state, this is a Bell type 
>   state, in a chosen basis $\{0,1,2\}$
>   \begin{equation*}
> \Omega _{0 0} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sum_{s=0}^2 |s\rangle \otimes
> |s\rangle\,.
> \end{equation*}
>   On the first subspace, the system of Alice, we act with the Weyl
>   operators, defined by $W_{k,l}|s\rangle = w^{k(s-l)}|s-l\rangle$
>   with $w=e^{2\pi i/3}$, while Bob's subsystem is always left inert.
>   The indexes $k$ and $l$ run from $0$ to $2$. The other eight Bell
>   states are constructed by acting with the Weyl operators onto the
>   chosen Bell state
>   \begin{equation*} \Omega_{k,l}=W_{k,l}\otimes I_3\;
> \Omega_{0,0}\,.
> \end{equation*}
>   With that we can construct nine Bell projectors $P_{k,l}=|\Omega_{k,
> l}\rangle\langle\Omega_{k,l}|$. The mixtures of these pure states
>   form our object of interest, the  magic simplex $W$:
>   \begin{equation*} 
> W\;=\; \{ \quad \sum
> c_{k l}\;P_{k,l} \; |\; c_{kl}\geq 0 , \quad \sum c_{k l}=1 \quad
> \}\end{equation*}

However, I'm not presently sure the given program is fully successful in the intended implementation. The trace of $P_{k,l}$ is 1 for $k=0,l=0$ and $\frac{2}{9}$ in the other eight cases (as indicated in the output above), while for a pure state I would expect them to be all 1. Also, I'm not sure as to the use of the `ConjugateTranspose` in the 2nd `Do` expression. Further, I also looked into the use of `TensorProduct`, rather than `KroneckerProduct`. Also, is the `ArrayReshape` command in the 2nd `Do` expression really necessary?

Obviously, this all strongly pertains to the use of physics (Dirac) notation — which I note has been the subject of a number of questions on this site.

Comment: `Omega[k, l]` is not correct: $|s-l \rangle$ is `S[s-l]`, not `S[s]-S[l]` (where $s-l\in{0,1,2}$): e.g. $s=2,l=1$, then $|s-l \rangle=|1 \rangle$, not `S[2]-S[1]`; also, I think in your code for $\Omega_{k,l}$, W has already acted on the 1st partite of $\Omega_{00}$, therefore the `Omega[0, 0]` in the definition of `Omega[k, l]` is redundant (you can check that your Omega[k,l] for $k,l\neq0$ is not a state vector)

Comment: also, it's better to use an array to store the basis vector `S[[i]]`, and the array index of mathematica starts with 1; additionally, it's better to present state vectors as n-by-1 vectors, so e.g. `S = Table[Null, {i, 1, 3}]; S[[1]] = {{1}, {0}, {0}};`

Comment: did some reading and it looks like the equation may miss a $mod$ (since $s-l$ needs to be in the set of $\{0,1,2\}$), see e.g. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/41/23/235303/meta

Comment: Yes, the subject of that last comment was also very much bothering me--and essentially compelled me to use S[s] - S[l], and not S[s-l]  . I'll check the indicated website. Also, I get to the same final result using the (more natural) code S[0] = {1, 0, 0}; S[1] = {0, 1, 0}; S[2] = {0, 0, 1};Omega[0, 0] = (1/Sqrt[3]) Sum[
   Flatten[Outer[Times, S[s], S[s]]], {s, 0, 2}];w = Exp[2 Pi I/3]; Do[
 If[{k, l} != {0, 0}, 
  Omega[k, l] = (1/Sqrt[3]) Sum[
     Flatten[Outer[Times, w^(k (s - l)) (S[s] - S[l]), S[s]]], {s, 0, 
      2}] Omega[0, 0]], {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 2}];

Comment: Do[P[k, l] = Outer[Times, Omega[k, l], Conjugate[Omega[k, l]]], {k, 0,
    2}, {l, 0, 2}];   So, no use of ArrayReshape.

Comment: I've written to the authors regarding the concern raised by egwene sedai above regarding s-l

Comment: Well, no word from the authors at this point, but if one consults their earlier  2006 paper https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0606083, immediately after eq. (3), it says: "Throughout this paper the letters {s, t, j, k, l, m, n, p, q} denote the numbers 0, 1, 2. Calculations with them are to be understood as “modulo 3”. So “1 + 2”= 0, “2 × 2”= 1, “−1”= 2, etc." So, this confirms the insight of egwene. However, at this point, I still don't seem to get all the traces of the P_{k,l}'s to equal 1--as seems necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to express this problem along the lines of what I teach in my book [Using Mathematica for Quantum Mechanics: A Student's Manual](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7050).

First, the basis states can be defined in many ways, for example as you do

```
S[0] = {1, 0, 0}; S[1] = {0, 1, 0}; S[2] = {0, 0, 1};
```

When taking tensor products of these, it's important to flatten out the result so that you end up with 9-vectors instead of 3x3-matrices:

```
Ω[0, 0] = 1/Sqrt[3] * Sum[Flatten[KroneckerProduct[S[s], S[s]]], {s, 0, 2}]
(*    {1/Sqrt[3], 0, 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 0, 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[3]}    *)
```

This means that the result contains only the first, fifth, and ninth basis function of the combined 9-dimensional vector space. These basis vectors are given by

```
Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 2]
(*    {{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,2}, {2,0}, {2,1}, {2,2}}    *)
```

so we see that $\Omega_{0,0}$ indeed only contains the basis functions $\lvert0,0\rangle=\lvert0\rangle\otimes\lvert0\rangle$, $\lvert1,1\rangle=\lvert1\rangle\otimes\lvert1\rangle$, and $\lvert2,2\rangle=\lvert2\rangle\otimes\lvert2\rangle$, as desired.

Now we define the Weyl operators with

```
w = E^(2*π*I/3);
W[k_, l_] := SparseArray[Table[{Mod[s-l, 3], s} + 1 -> w^(k*(s-l)), {s, 0, 2}], {3, 3}]
```

(using the `mod` function as suggested by @egwenesedai in the comments). They are 3x3-matrices. From here we get the Bell states

```
Ω[k_, l_] := KroneckerProduct[W[k, l], IdentityMatrix[3]] . Ω[0, 0]
```

where each $\Omega_{k,l}$ is a 9-vector, found by multiplying $\Omega_{0,0}$ by a 9x9-matrix, which in turn is the Kronecker product of two 3x3-matrices.

Finally, the Bell projectors are 9x9-matrices,

```
P[k_, l_] := KroneckerProduct[Ω[k, l], Conjugate[Ω[k, l]]]
```

and you can check that their traces are all 1:

```
Table[Tr[P[k, l]], {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 2}]
(*    {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}    *)
```

For deeper info I'd recommend you have a look at chapter 2 of my book referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

Consulting the preceding  paper, "The state space for two qutrits has a phase space structure in its core", of the three authors (B. Baumgartner, B. C. Hiesmayr and H. Narnhofer) https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0606083, we find in their sec. 3, the explicit representations of the nine Weyl operators $W_{k,l}$, (k, l =0, 1, 2):

```
[W[0, 0] = IdentityMatrix[3]; W[0, 1] = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}; W[0, 2] = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}; W[1, 0] = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, w, 0}, {0, 0,Conjugate[w]}};  W[1, 1] = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, w}, {Conjugate[w], 0, 0}}; W[1, 2] = {{0, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 0},{0, Conjugate[w], 0}}; W[2, 0] = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Conjugate[w], 0}, {0, 0, w}}; W[2, 1] = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, Conjugate[w]}, {w, 0, 0}}; W[2, 2] = {{0, 0, 1}, {Conjugate[w], 0, 0}, {0, w, 0}}]
```

where $w = e^{\frac{2 i \pi }{3}}$.

Together, with the previously-given assertion,
\begin{equation*} \Omega_{k,l}=W_{k,l}\otimes I_3\;
\Omega_{0,0}\,,
\end{equation*}
it appears that the following code achieves the stated goal of constructing  the "magical simplex $\mathcal{W}$ of bipartite qutrits"

```
S[0] = {1, 0, 0}; S[1] = {0, 1, 0}; S[2] = {0, 0, 1}; Omega[0, 0] = (1/Sqrt[3]) Sum[TensorProduct[S[s], S[s]], {s, 0, 2}]; Do[Omega1[k, l] = ArrayReshape[TensorProduct[W[k, l], IdentityMatrix[3] Omega[0, 0]], {9, 9}]/Sqrt[3], {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 2}]; Do[P[k, l] = Outer[Times, Omega1[k, l].ConjugateTranspose[Omega1[k, l]]], {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 2}]; Do[Print[{k, l, Sum[P[k, l][[i, i]], {i, 1, 9}]}], {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 2}]
```

The last command Do[Print[{k, l, Sum[P[k, l][[i, i]], {i, 1, 9}]}], {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 2}] confirms that the traces (sums of diagonal entries) of the nine Bell projectors $P_{k,l}$ are all unity.

(In light of the earlier comments of egwene sedai and me, let us also note the authors' statement that "Throughout this paper the letters
$\{s,t,j,k,\ell,m,n,p,q\}$ denote the numbers $0, 1, 2$.
Calculations with them are to be understood as ``modulo 3''.")

With this construction of the 8-dimensional simplex, we hope to obtain the Hilbert-Schmidt probability that a member (two-qutrit [$9 \times 9$ density matrix]) of the simplex, 
\begin{equation*} 
W\;=\; \{ \quad \sum
c_{k l}\;P_{k,l} \; |\; c_{kl}\geq 0 , \quad \sum c_{k l}=1 \quad
\}\end{equation*} 
has a positive partial transpose (PPT) and, further, the (sub)-probability that any member with a PPT is also separable--that is, the convex combination of product (qutrit) states. (Contrastingly, by the famous Peres-Horodecki result, for lower-dimensional $6 \times 6$ and $4 \times 4$ density matrices, the PPT-property is equivalent--not just necessary--for separability to hold. PPT-states that are not separable, are termed "bound entangled".)